# Is it possible to create a complex filter with php FUEL SDK?

Tags: php, fuel-sdk, filters

I currently using in my project:

https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP

I don't find any documentation on how to perform a get with a complex filter:

```
        $myClient = new ET_Client($config);
        $dataextensionrow           = new ET_DataExtension_Row();
        $dataextensionrow->authStub = $myClient;
        $dataextensionrow->Name     = 'Transactional_SendLog22';
        $dataextensionrow->props    = array(
            'SubscriberID',                
            'unix_ts'
        );
        $dataextensionrow->filter = [
            [
                'LeftOperand'=> ['Property' => 'unix_ts','SimpleOperator' => 'greaterThanOrEqual','Value' => "1"],
                'LogicalOperator' => 'AND',
                'RightOperand'=> ['Property' => 'SubscriberID','SimpleOperator' => 'Equal','Value' => "1"]
            ]
        ];

        $results = $dataextensionrow->get();
```

This code is producing the following error:

> SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Property' property in ../salesforce-mc/fuel-sdk-php/src/ET_Get.php

How am I supposed to write a filter with a logical operator with Fuel SDK for php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check the below sample code which uses ComplexFilterPart using LogicalOperator:
https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/FuelSDK-PHP/blob/master/objsamples/sample-folder.php

Please make your filter line code like below:

```
$getFolder->filter = array(
   'LeftOperand' => 
      array('Property'=>'ParentFolder.ID','SimpleOperator'=>'equals','Value'=>'0'), 
   'LogicalOperator' => 'AND', 
   'RightOperand' => 
      array('Property'=>'ContentType','SimpleOperator'=>'equals','Value'=>'EMAIL'));
```

Also try to use SimpleOperator as mentioned below:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/simpleoperators.htm